# $controller not getting instantiated in jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

This snippet of code is giving error when running my test case.

```
 beforeEach(module(function($scope) {

// do something interesting with the service
//console.log($controller);

}));
```

Error coming up in console.

```
debug.js:21 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate    
module function ($scope) due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scope
```

Could anyone please explain why it is not able to find $scope. It is also not working if I change it to $timeout or $controller.

**Updated Code
If I change the code to this**

Then it works

```
module(function($controllerProvider) {
// we could also access the $controllerProvider.allowGlobals() function, 
// which allows us to register a controller on the window object.
$controllerProvider.register('ProductsController', function() {
    // logic of the controller...
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two different functions `module` and `inject`.

`module` configures the jasmine environment to use the angular module you specify. That's probably `app`.  If you don't call this, the injector will not be able to find your services, controllers, directives, etc.  In the `module` function, you can inject [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers), not services, factories, etc.  You use providers to *configure* how the services will behave later.

`inject` takes the function you supply and "injects" the services, constants, factories, etc by name before calling it.  You use this to inejct the services etc themselves.

Here's a sample of how to split the calls in your code.  I also changed the `$scope` to use `$rootScope` and create a scope.

```
 beforeEach(function() {
    module("app"); //or if your module is name something different, use that name instead

    inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        var myCtrl = $controller("myCtrl", { $scope: $scope });
    }));
});
```

Comment: There are 3 ways to pass argument in module function 1. String 2. Function 3. Object Literal.

Comment: @user3045179 all three do different things.  If you use a string argument, it finds a module with that name.  If you use a function, it uses that function *to create a new module*.  If you use an object, it inits one module for each property. You can review [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module) for more information.

Comment: You are right about above, but I think when you are using module, it is not able to find $scope in the provider cache.

Comment: @user3045179 When using module, you're at the *wrong stage* to get `$scope`.  `module` can inject providers to configure them.  Also, you can never inject `$scope` to a plain function.  You can inject `$rootScope` and use that to *create a scope*.